# cannot make array in C

Tags: c

I am trying to make an array that prints the numbers from 1 to 40 like this:

```
1  5  9   13  17  21  25  29  33  37
2  6  10  14  18  22  26  30  34  38
3  7  11  15  19  23  27  31  35  39
4  8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40
```

I have tried it but i cannot do it. here is my code:

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{

    for(j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
    if(i=0)
    {
        array[i][j]= 
    }

    }
}

for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", array[i][j]);    
    }

}
```

Thank for your help

Comment: That code won't even compile.

Comment: What is the type of your array, how did you initialize it ? what is the end of `array[i][j]= ` ?

Comment: array[i][j] = (j * 4) + (i + 1);

Comment: the type of array is int. there is no end of array[i][j]=.. i dont know what to do next.. i have tried everything

Comment: thank you Ryan Fitzpatrick. it works

Comment: Array not required. http://ideone.com/kICnmZ

Comment: @Γιώργος Καλογεράς - np glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

There are a whole bunch of problems, which people are noting. I've noticed that in the comments (by the time I'd finished writing this) you've said "it works" once you added the right assign. God knows how, but presumably the code in your question is not representative of your actual code...

For posterity, problems listed below.

### 1. Declaration

You need to declare array[][] at the start of the function/Main/Program

```
int array[10][4];
```

you also need to define i and j and set them as 0. Presumably you're doing all this outside the posted code.

Note that I've swapped around the "i" and "j" values you've been using. This is because [4][10] will give you 4 arrays of 10 elements, not 10 arrays of 4 elements, which is what you apparently want.

### 2. Order of cycling through the array

you want the numbers to go down before they go across. In order to get that pattern you need to be cycling through the "i" value faster than the "j":

```
for(j=0;i<10;i++)
{
    for(i=0;i<4;j++)
   {
   ...
   }
}
```

### 3.The Assign

I have no idea what this if statement is meant to be doing:

```
if(i=0)
{
 ... 
}
```

Not only will this **ALWAYS** return **false**, it will set i back to 0 every time so you'll just keep overwriting the first element and your for loop will never end. I would consider taking this out as it is doing nothing.

As @JohnBode pointed out, i=0 returns 0 (an assignment operation always returns the value being assigned), so this if statement is equivalent to if(0), which will always be false.

The assign is then relatively simple:

```
array[i][j] = (i + 1) + (4*j)
```

Note the +1's as the array index will be one less than the required value. I think the calculation is correct, it might be slightly wrong by to be honest that's the least of your worries with this code!

The print function is fine. As far as I can tell that's everything!

Comment: +1 lol I just about to make my comment with the same formula into an answer, you beat me to it by second :)

Comment: Nit: `if (i=0)` will always evaluate to *false*, so the body of the `if` statement will never be executed.

Comment: @JohnBode Good point, I had been thinking about it that the assignment returns true as in  "successful assignment", but it returns the value of the assignment doesn't it (and there's no such thing as true natively in C, too much C++). I've updated my answer!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably read more, and practice more basic coding problems.

---

As you are storing the numbers row-wize, you need to code that way only

```
int arr[4][10], i, j, count = 1;

for(i=0;i<10;i++)       //this is for columns
{
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)    //this is for the rows
    {
        array[j][i] = count++;
        //array is accessed with [j][i] because you want to move row-wize down
        //count is keeping track of the number to be stored
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got the question right, but I would suggest you to try something like this:

```
int i, j,array[4][10], number=0;

    for (j =0; j < 10; j++) {
        for (i=0; i < 4; i++) {
            array[i%4][j] = ++number;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<4;i++) {  
        for(j=0;j<10;j++) {
            printf("%d\t", array[i][j]);    
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Why `i%4` when `i < 4`?!

Comment: Just to make sure it goes to the right line, the possible results for i % 4 when I goes from 0 to 4, are 0, 1, 2 and 3. But you could also do array[j][i] instead of array [i %4] [j]

Comment: But… `for (i=0; i < 4; i++)` means `i` will *never* be greater than or equal to 4. And no, you couldn't use `array[j][i]` since `j` *will* be greater than 4.

Comment: oh yes, right I didn't see i changed the order of the for's :D

Answer (score 0):

Very simple code, in order to get the concept
- it can probably done much more better, but the target is to show you the concept here simply:

```
//Initialize your counter variable.
int count = 1;

//Declare rows, columns.
int row, col;

//Declare your array. 4 Rows, 10 Columns.
int array[4][10];

//Iterate columns.
for(col = 0; col < 10; col = col + 1)
{
    //Iterate rows.
    for(row = 0; row < 4; row = row + 1)
    {
        array[row][col] = count;

        count = count + 1;
    }

}
```

You can then simply iterate and print your array:

```
for(row = 0; row < 4; row = row + 1)
{
    for(col = 0; col < 10; col = col + 1)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[row][col]);
    }
    //Print newline at the end of the row.
    printf("\n");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the pattern in the first row:

```
1  5  9   13  17  21  25  29  33  37
```

Start with 1, add 4 to get 5, add 4 to get 9, etc.  So to get the value for each column, you add the number of rows to a starting value:

```
for ( column_number = 0; column_number < max_cols; column_number++ )
  column_value = start_value + max_rows * column_number
```

Your `start_value` is the same as the row number: 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.

```
for ( row_number = 1; row_number <= max_rows; row_number++ )
{
  for ( column_number = 0; column_number < max_columns; column_number++ )
  {
    column_value = row_number + max_rows * column_number;
  }
}
```

So the value for each `a[i][j]` is `(i+1) + j * max_rows` (assuming you want to start with `1`; remember that arrays in C are always indexed from 0 to N-1);

Note that you don't need an array to do this, though:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  /**
   * Specify default values
   */
  int rows = 4;
  int cols = 10;
  int initialValue = 1;

  /**
   * Override defaults with command-line parameters, if any
   */
  if ( argc > 3 )
    initialValue = (int) strtol( argv[3], NULL, 10 );

  if ( argc > 2 )
    cols = (int) strtol( argv[2], NULL, 10 );

  if ( argc > 1 )
    rows = (int) strtol( argv[1], NULL, 10 );

  /**
   * Print the table
   */
  for ( int i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
  {
    for ( int j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
    {
      printf("%2d    ", (initialValue + i) + j * rows );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This code prints out the table without using an array.  It also allows you to specify the rows, columns, and start value on the command line, with the default values being 4, 10, and 1 respectively:

```
$ ./rows
 1     5     9    13    17    21    25    29    33    37
 2     6    10    14    18    22    26    30    34    38
 3     7    11    15    19    23    27    31    35    39
 4     8    12    16    20    24    28    32    36    40

$ ./rows 10 4
 1    11    21    31
 2    12    22    32
 3    13    23    33
 4    14    24    34
 5    15    25    35
 6    16    26    36
 7    17    27    37
 8    18    28    38
 9    19    29    39
10    20    30    40

$ ./rows 5 5 0
 0     5    10    15    20
 1     6    11    16    21
 2     7    12    17    22
 3     8    13    18    23
 4     9    14    19    24
```